# Could somebody explain how this server program closes it's socket after every connection? And how could I keep the socket open?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, uwp

So I want to make an TCP connection between 2 UWP apps using streamsockets. I found this example on the microsoft webpage and it works. The problem is that it closes it's sockets after every connection that's been established. I want to understand when it closes(can't find it in the code and that confuses me a bit) and I also want to know how I could keep the connection between server and client open so I don't have to reconnect every time I want to send something.

Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets#build-a-basic-tcp-socket-client-and-server

I have looked in the StreamSocket documentation on Windows and can't really find things about closing the socket.

I assume it happens somewhere in this method. It's the server side of the program that is executed when a connection is received.

```
private async void StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived
(Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener sender,   
Windows.Networking.Sockets.
StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    string request;
    using (var streamReader = new   
    StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
    {
        request = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
    }

    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>    this.serverListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("server received the request: \"{0}\"", request)));

// Echo the request back as the response.
using (Stream outputStream = args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
    {
        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(request);
        await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
    }
}

string request;
using (var streamReader = new
StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
{
    request = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
}

await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
this.serverListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("server received the 
request: \"{0}\"", request)));

// Echo the request back as the response.
using (Stream outputStream =   
args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
    {
        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(request);
        await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
    }
}

await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
this.serverListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("server sent back the 
response: \"{0}\"", request)));

sender.Dispose();

await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
this.serverListBox.Items.Add("server closed its socket"));
```

}

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> I found this example on the microsoft webpage and it works.

Unfortunately, all the Microsoft socket examples are **not** good examples of how to write socket applications. They are **only** examples on how to call those APIs. Building a production-quality socket application is non-trivial, and the Microsoft socket examples will mislead you.

For example, this socket server:

- Uses `Dispatcher` to update the UI rather than modern solutions like `IProgress<T>`.
- Reads from its input stream until a newline is found. This is a problem because:

  - There is no timeout for the request to arrive.
  - The input buffer grows without bounds.
  - There's no handling of the half-open scenario.

Most socket examples from Microsoft have the same problems, all of which have to be addressed when writing production-quality socket code. And writing production-quality socket code is much harder than it first appears.

For this reason, I always recommend using an alternative technology (e.g., self-hosted SignalR) if possible.

But to answer your actual question:

> I want to understand when it closes

With sockets, there are actually *two* streams: an input stream and output stream. Both are closed when `sender.Dispose();` is called. However, the input stream is *also* closed when the `StreamReader` is disposed, and the output stream is *also* closed when the `StreamWriter` is disposed. These happen at the end of their `using` blocks. This is why you cannot read the second message after closing the `StreamReader`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do understand the code a bit better now.

Comment: I am going to explore SignalR because I really enjoy learning about sockets